# how to define new various in PHP function

Tags: php

I want to define **new** variable in a function .

```
function show()
{//for e.g
    $name = "john";
    $family = "cina";
    $old = "45";
}
show();
echo "your name is $name ";//in another  line
echo "your family is $family ";//in another line
echo "your old is $old ";//in another  line
```

Thanks

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/3933332

Comment: Variables created inside a function, only exist in that scope. Please read the post that Rizier123 linked. You can't use them anywhere else but inside the function where you created the variables

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks but it dosnt help me.

Comment: @mrjohn Have you read it? PHP has function scope for variables, so you have to return your variables from the function (probably want to do it with an array) and then assign the return value back to variables in a `list()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, don't do this. It's not very good and looks terrible, but this is what you need.

```
<?php 
$name = null;
$family = null;
$old = null;
function show()
{
   global $name, $family, $old;
   $name = "john";
   $family = "cina";
   $old = "45";
}

show();
echo "your name is $name ".PHP_EOL;
echo "your family is $family ".PHP_EOL;
echo "your old is $old ".PHP_EOL;
```

I will recommend an alternative way of writing this (one of many). You can check other answers for different ways.

```
class Singleton {
      public static $name;
      public static $family;
      public static $old;
}

function show()
{
   Singleton::$name = "john";
   Singleton::$family = "cina";
   Singleton::$old = "45";
}

show();
echo "your name is ".Singleton::$name;//in another  line
echo "your family is ".Singleton::$family;//in another line
echo "your old is ".Singleton::$old;//in another  line
```

Comment: When you already say don't do it, why do you show that to OP? This can be solved much better.

Comment: Thanks . I need this exactly

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123 :)

Comment: That's not a clean example. It shows poorly and dirty coding. Go for the answer below.

Comment: @DominikK this answer was written a year ago and is already accepted so I can't delete it nor would down-voting move it lower in the results making it kind of stuck here no matter what happens. At any rate I've added an alternative solution which avoids globals.

Comment: Yeah no worries mate, I know that. I just wanted to point this out to the future generation.

Answer (score 3):

You could also consider using [list();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) you'll have to make a slight change to your function but it'll work.

```
function show(){
   $name = "john";
   $family = "cina";
   $old = "45";

   return array($name,$family,$old);
}

list($name,$family,$old) = show(); 

echo $name;
echo $family;
echo $old;
```

Be aware that the order matters, the first value in the `return array` will be assigned to the first variable in the `list();` and the second array value to the second variable in the list, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Write echo inside function as below

```
function show()
{
   $name = "john";
   $family = "cina";
   $old = "45";
   echo $name." ".$family." ".$old;
}
show();
```

Comment: No i need to define new variable this is just a e.g

Comment: You can define variable whatever you want

Answer (score 2):

```
function show()
{
   $name = "john";
   $family = "cina";
   $old = "45";
   return $name." ".$family." ".$old;
}
echo show();
```

This

Comment: This work but i need to use variable in different lines . i want to just define variable.thanks

Answer (score 2):

Return it from your function like this

```
function show()
{//for e.g
$name = "john";
$family = "cina";
$old = "45";
return $name . " " . $family . " " . $old;
}
$result = show();
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use also in the following way

```
function show()
{
  $name = "john";
  $family = "cina";
  $old = "45";
  return $name." ".$family." ".$old;
 }
 echo      $res = show(); // john cina 45
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I should do it =)

```
<?php

function show()
{
   $name = "john";
   $family = "cina";
   $old = "45";
   echo $name." ".$family." ".$old;
}
show();

?>
```